# How to filter elements which contains null references in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

So currently I am trying to wrap my head around java 8.

I have this stream manipulation

```
    List<MyObject> parsedEvents = events.stream()
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(
         e -> MyObject.builder()
.setFoo(e.foo())
.setBar(e.bar())
.setBaz(e.baz())
.build()
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But, sometimes e.foo() can be Null or e.bar() can be null or e.baz() can be null.

So, I want to just filter those events where any of those methods will return a null.

What's a clean way to do that in java 8.

Comment: add a condition to your existing filter that is desired as such, or are you looking for anything else? pertaining to the title, its purely a duplicate.

Comment: There is no such thing as a null object, only null references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
List<MyObject> parsedEvents = events.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(e -> Stream.of(e.foo(), e.bar(), e.baz())
        .allMatch(Objects::nonNull))
    .map(
        e -> MyObject.builder()
            .setFoo(e.foo())
            .setBar(e.bar())
            .setBaz(e.baz())
            .build())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```